# Measure of Improvement in Math Skills from Remediation with ALEKS

Tags: education, learning

I am analyzing some data on ALEKS for my home institution. Specifically, I am analyzing placement scores for ALEKS where the students are allowed to take the placement test multiple times and are given the chance to improve their background (i.e. remediate) using ALEKS in between test attempts. My data set consists of the ALEKS placement test scores and the total time spent in remediation with ALEKS (for each student).

I am trying to find a ballpark estimate for the expected average rate of improvement (in terms of number of new topics learned or % increase in score) a student should see from remediation. I would like to have some benchmark with which to compare the rate of improvement from my data set. In other words, are my students doing better, worse , or about the same as expected using the remediation available via ALEKS?

Thank you,

Matthew Brenneman

Comment: No, I want to have some benchmark with which to compare the rate of improvement from my data set. In other words, are my students doing better, worse , or about the same as expected using the remediation available via ALEKS?

Comment: This is an interdisciplinary question and rules, after all, are really guidelines. Considering how difficult it is to find someone who knows this information, I would ask for a little latitude on the part of the mods.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question, I deleted my comments.

Comment: Actually thank you for your question littleO: my original question really wasn't that clear.